# Post array using clone of select

Tags: php, arrays, post, clone

I have my code in PHP, and I'm using a select box, built in one array. What I pretend is to clone the select with jQuery for add how many rows I want.

Example:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id='add_line_class'>Adicionar classe</a><a class='icon add_btn_icon activated_icon'></a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id='rem_line_class'>Remover classe</a><a class='icon cross_btn_icon'></a>
<table id="tbl_add_class" border="0" width="100%">
<tr id="add_new_class">
<td style="width:30%"><strong>Classe:</strong>&nbsp;
<select name="var_class[]">
  <option value="A"><A</option>
  <option value="B"><B</option>
  <option value="C"><C</option>
</select>
</td></tr>
</table>
```

Then my jQuery to clone the select, using the ID:

```
$(document).on('click',"#add_line_class", function(){
    var content = $('#add_new_class').clone(true);
    $('#add_new_class').after(content);
});
```

Till now everything ok and it clones, but I want to pass the values through the POST of PHP, for receive in the next step/page. It passes well the first select (php original select), but doesn't pass the jQuery values (the clone).

Do I need to use post by ajax or something ? or any other idea to solve the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: should '#add_line_class' be '#add_new_class'?

Comment: the click is with a button (<a href=''...></a>) to add lines (selects). So the "#add_cline_class" is the <a> html tag and the "add_new_class" is the id of <tr> tag.

Comment: can you show all the code please? (including the <a> tags)

Comment: I've edited above. See it please.

Comment: the problem is on the jQuery that doesn't pass my option value..

Answer (score 0):

i tried with your code.It works well cloning of elements and `POST` data of cloned elements.If you want to get the `POST` values of data when click on submit button try like this in your php code

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['var_class']);$i++)
    {

        $rows[$i]['item_name'] = $_POST['var_class'][$i];
    }

    foreach($rows as $row)
    {
        print_r($row);
    }

}
```

In your `HTML` try to change like this.

```
<input type="button" onClick="javascript:submit_form();" value="Passo 2 >>" style="width:100px"/>
```

In your `JavaScript` write like this

```
function submit_form()
{
      // You can do here validations
    document.form1.action='test.php?step=2';
    document.form1.submit();
}
```

Then it will works. Please try like that.

If this code not resolves your problem please explain more.So that i can help you. Thanks.

Comment: Still the same, just pass the PHP select (first one), like Array ( [item_name] => H ) . I've tried to put your code in a test page, but still not working. In the count($_POST['var_class'], just count 1!

Comment: Could you explain exactly your expected output. So that i will help you.

Comment: I tried your code for cloning elements http://jsfiddle.net/tkaz5n8v/. Now here your submitting the form. Is it like that. Please give me more explanation of your exact result or post the your code what you want

Comment: I expected the result that you obtained, but in my case it just pass the first item. Maybe because of my submit form, but it's a normal submit like: <form method="post" id="form1" action="">

Comment: On my input button I have this <input type="button" onClick="submit_form('form1','airservice_add2.php?step=2')" value="Passo 2 >>" style="width:100px"/>

Comment: Hi @pedroF, i updated my answer. please try like that. you will get result.Thanks

Comment: I saw. but I think that we cannot use "document.form1.action", that's why: TypeError: document.form1 is undefined. I figured out other solution.. but still without pass the jquery values.

Comment: You missed declaring form name. Please make sure declare your form name.`<form method="post" name="form1" id="form1">`. Now try

Comment: yes that worked. But the post always in the same.. just the first element. If I pass an hidden input with the post? Should work?

Comment: Fine.For one element also you didn't get any problem.`print_r($row)` here try to replace your code. If you try `echo $row['var_class']`. it will displays only one element.

Comment: I didn't get  your point. But I see by the console that passes only the first element..